# DPMS and HDMI audio

Tags: hdmi, plasma, screensaver, xset

While playing audio through HDMI connection, the audio is turned off once DPMS kicks in. This is somewhat expected. But I'd like to have the screen blanked and keep the audio playing...

DPMS has this blanking option (`xset s blank` + `xset s on`), which should just render black screen without turning on any other power-saving measures (as per documentation). The problem is, whatever I do with these settings, DPMS always suspends my monitors, thus shutting off my audio playback.

I'm aware `xscreensaver` (with DPMS off) can do *almost* what I want - render a black window (which tricks my monitors to turn off backlight) while keeping my audio playing. The problem is I'd like to integrate it with my shell's power management suspension features (KDE Plasma atm.).

Is there any proven solution to this problem?

I can write my own service listening on `dbus` and handling the idle-change signals by hand, but I'd like not to re-invent the wheel, if possible :-) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I wrote my own connector in python. It sits on `dbus`, monitoring screensaver un/inhibit method calls and disrupts a running `xscreensaver` instance as needed. I'll add some configurability, convert it to a `systemd` service and create an AUR package out of it eventually...

https://github.com/Heehaaw/dbus-xscreensaver-connector